# Cross Browser Extension

Tags: typescript, browser-extension

I am trying to write an extension using TypeScript that works across all browsers.  I have found this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-ext-types which I am using and I have set up in my package.json.

In typescript I can type browser and see all the intellisense, etc. but when I run it in Chrome I get the exception:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: browser is not defined.
```

My code is below:

```
browser.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener((e) => {
    console.log("webNavigation onHistoryStateUpdated");
    console.log(e);
    // do something here
});
```

I am very new to typescript and browser extensions, if I change to Chrome it works fine but then will not be supported in IE/Firefox (maybe firefox?).  I have found this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/browser-extension-edge-chrome-firefox-opera-brave-vivaldi/ which suggests putting this in:

```
window.browser = (function () {
    return window.msBrowser ||
        window.browser ||
        window.chrome;
})();
```

My question is should I have to or should the web-ext-types handle this?  Also when I try to put this anywhere in TypeScript I get the error:

property browser does not exist on type window.  Currently I am also including:

> "@types/chrome": "~0.0.63",

Should I remove this if I am using web-ext-types?  I am also using chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged which doesn't seem to be in browser.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been down voted but would appreciate any help.

Comment: What does the browser extension do?

Comment: well, the thing is browser is not defined, thats why it doesnt work

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding.  I understand it’s not defined in chrome, and appears to be defined as msBrowser in edge, although haven’t tried directly but have read as such.  I’m hoping for a single piece of code working across chrome, Firefox and edge written in typescript.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [chrome.history.onVisited.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history), it doesn't do exactly the same as it does in chrome but the functionality is similar.

as far as I know there is no "browser" variable on chrome, however, you might be able to make some sort of polyfill, it could work, in principle. 
Like some sort of jQuery for browser extensions.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I will have a look at your suggestion.  It looks like the suggestion is to use chrome not browser and polyfill for edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/porting-chrome-extensions